# Bootstrap 4 toggle / Radio buttons group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a "toggle" (don't know if the name is right) from bootstrap 4. I couldn't find any clue on the documentation about how to do this.

[image: Toggle button]

I've tried to create a "radio button group", but i'm having issues with this method and still see the radio circles on my buttons.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: show your tried code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I understand properly:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-warning active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-warning">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-warning">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
  </label>
</div>
```

Check out the [**Checkbox and radio buttons**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons) Documentation.

Comment: Thansk for the answer, i actually found it in the documentation. I missed it the first time..

Comment: checked doesn't work for me with data-toggle=buttons. How can I get a radio selected when a page loads?

Answer (score 6):

I actually found the answer! For those who want to see what it looks like :

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-toggle active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-toggle">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-toggle">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> 3
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Acctualy @awran5 answerer your question. ;)

Comment: @awran5 answer didn't work for me, but this one.